# Check whether exists index k such that elements of array A[] moved clockwise make a reverse bitonic array

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, verification

Check whether exists index `0 <= k < n - 2` such that elements of array `A[]` moved clockwise by `k` indexes make a reverse bitonic array.
My approach to do it in **O(n)** time complexity:

```
bool is_antibitonicable(int A[], int n) {
    // returns if there is such index k that 
    // after moving clockwise k elements of array
    // A[], that array is reverse bitonic
    // - strictly decreasing then strictly
    // increasing
    if (n < 3)
        return false;
    // if is_increasing[i] == 1 means this part of A[] is increasing,
    // == 0 means that part of A[] is decreasing, == -1 default
    int is_increasing[3] = { -1, -1, -1 };
    for (int i = 0, j; i < n - 1;) {
        if (A[i] < A[i + 1]) { // if A[] is increasing
            j = 0;
            while (j < 3 && is_increasing[j] != -1)
                j++;
            if (j == 3)
                return false;
            is_increasing[j] = 1;
            while (i < n - 1 && A[i] < A[i + 1])
                i++;
        }
        else if (A[i] > A[i + 1]) { // check if decreasing
            j = 0;
            while (j < 3 && is_increasing[j] != -1)
                j++;
            if (j == 3)
                return false;
            is_increasing[j] = 0;
            while (i < n - 1 && A[i] > A[i + 1])
                i++;
        }
        else // sequence of A[] is neither increasing nor decreasing
            return false;
    }
    // if A[] is only increasing/decreasing
    if (is_increasing[1] == is_increasing[2])
        return false;
    // if A[] is increasing->decreasing->increasing check if increasing
    // parts can be merged into one increasing sequence
    if (is_increasing[0] == 1 && is_increasing[1] == 0 && is_increasing[2] == 1)
        return (A[0] > A[n - 1]);
    // decreasing->increasing->decreasing
    if (is_increasing[0] == 0 && is_increasing[1] == 1 && is_increasing[2] == 0)
        return (A[0] < A[n - 1]);
    return true; // increasing -> decreasing or opposite
}
```

I'd be very glad if someone could look at my solution and comment whether it seems correct or how to do it better, any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Write a bunch of testcases and see if it is passing

Comment: @EugeneSh. sure i did, just curious if I'm not missing something or doing something unnecessery ;)

Comment: What is "moving (elements of) an array _clockwise_" supposed to mean?

Comment: @Armali clockwise rotation, e.g. 1,2,3,5 -> 3,5,1,2 for k == 2.

Comment: The term _clockwise_ implies movement around a circle. There is no common mapping of an array to a circle; an array is usually depicted along a (directed) straight line. The usual term for your described transformation is _rotate_ _left_ or _right_ (your example doesn't make clear which direction you have in mind).

Comment: @Armali note that it does not matter what direction you choose, the task is about checking whether its possible, not to return such index :). I wasn't sure about the terminology but i googled a similar problem concerning arrays and it used the term clockwise rotation.

Comment: The direction would not matter if only the movement wouldn't be limited to `k < n - 2` in your task description (which the implementation doesn't seem to follow). Are you sure it shouldn't rather be `k < n`?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't look bad, but it does incorrectly `return false` `// if A[] is only increasing/decreasing`. Such a sequence can always be turned into a first decreasing and then increasing one by rotating by one in the *right* (appropriate) direction.

Comment: strictly increasing sequence cannot be turned into a reverse bitonic sequence without reversing order of a part of the sequence if I'm not wrong, maybe I didn't explain the problem good enough or wrong in my post.

Comment: I think you are wrong; consider [1, 2, 3, 4] rotated right by 1 => [4, 1, 2, 3]. Isn't that a _reverse bitonic sequence_?